# Exclude worksheets from loop with a list

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a loop through all my worksheets to collcet data on the first worksheet. Now I want to exclude a list of worksheets that is defines by their namees in a list on the first worksheet.

I could exclude them one by one like this:

```
dim ws as worksheet
For each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" and ws.name <> "Sheet2"
```

and so on.

BUT
Since the data will change in the future I dont want to edit this code everytime the "exclude-list" changes.

**UPDATE**
I have tried the solution from "CLR" because it seemed like an easy way to fix it and it worked for my case. Just a reminder: You also have to include the name of the worksheet you want to diaplay your data on in the list and you are used to the `If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" and ws.name <> "Sheet2"` method. All the other solutions might work too, when I have the time I might test them, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Process worksheets of active workbook, excluding those on a list in a specified range:**

Modify the A1:A6 address to the location of your exclusion list. Modify the Sheet1 part if your list is on another named sheet.

```
Sub ProcessWorksheets()
    
    'declarations
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim exceptionlist As Range
    
    'define range that contains exceptions
    Set exceptionlist = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A6")
    
    'cycle through each worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        'if ws.name does not exist in the range
        If Application.CountIf(exceptionlist, ws.Name) = 0 Then
            'do something with ws
            Debug.Print ws.Name
        Else
            'ignore it, do nothing
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a sheet named Exclude.
On column A write Exclude on first line.
Your other sheets to exclude after. Finally, use code below..

```
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set rs = ws.Range("A1:A1" & Lastrow)


For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not rs.Find(ws.Name) Is Nothing Then
        'Your code
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

### Loop Through Worksheets Excluding the Ones in a List

- Test this code as-is before adding your processing code assuring yourself that it works correctly i.e. that it includes the correct worksheets.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CollectData()

    ' Define constants.
    Const LIST_WORKSHEET_ID = 1 ' rather use the (tab name), e.g. "Sheet1"
    Const LIST_FIRST_CELL As String = "Z2"

    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the list range.
    Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = wb.Sheets(LIST_WORKSHEET_ID)
    Dim lfCell As Range: Set lfCell = lws.Range(LIST_FIRST_CELL)
    Dim llCell As Range
    Set llCell = lws.Cells(lws.Rows.Count, lfCell.Column).End(xlUp)
    Dim lrg As Range: Set lrg = lws.Range(lfCell, llCell)
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    
    ' Loop through all worksheets...
    For Each sws In wb.Worksheets
        ' ... excluding the ones from the list:
        If IsError(Application.Match(sws.Name, lrg, 0)) Then
            
            ' Continue using the 'sws' variable , e.g.:
            Debug.Print sws.Name
        
        'Else ' it's one from the list; do nothing
        End If
    Next sws
    
    MsgBox "Data collected.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```